# Warning: Killing the server while running scrcpy

Tags: usb, android, snap, 21.10, scrcpy

Today, I was trying to operate my mobile phone using my Laptop (Ubuntu 21.10). I found an interesting application that allows me to operate my mobile phone using Ubuntu. The application is known as [Scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy). I followed all the steps of [README.md](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/blob/master/README.md) and installed it using `sudo snap install scrcpy`. After allowing all the permissions (USB debugging and Security USB debugging) on my android phone, I tried to run it, however, it gives me the following errors:

```
$ scrcpy

INFO: scrcpy 1.19 <https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy>
/usr/local/share/scrcpy/scrcpy-server:...shed. 0.8 MB/s (37330 bytes in 0.042s)
[server] INFO: Device: XXXXXX NNNNN (Android 10)
[server] ERROR: Exception on thread Thread[main,5,main]
android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Error 0xfffffff4
    at android.media.MediaCodec.native_configure(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:2024)
    at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:1952)
    at com.genymobile.scrcpy.ScreenEncoder.configure(ScreenEncoder.java:237)
    at com.genymobile.scrcpy.ScreenEncoder.internalStreamScreen(ScreenEncoder.java:90)
    at com.genymobile.scrcpy.ScreenEncoder.streamScreen(ScreenEncoder.java:61)
    at com.genymobile.scrcpy.Server.scrcpy(Server.java:80)
    at com.genymobile.scrcpy.Server.main(Server.java:255)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:380)
INFO: Renderer: opengl
INFO: OpenGL version: 2.1 Mesa 20.0.8
WARN: Trilinear filtering disabled (OpenGL 3.0+ or ES 2.0+ required)
INFO: Initial texture: 1080x2336
WARN: Device disconnected
WARN: Killing the server...
```

**Some information**

- Scrcpy was installed using `sudo snap install scrcpy`
- All permissions are given on my android phone.
- It is the latest Redmi note 10 pro (8GB - 128GB)
- All scrcpy settings are default.
- I am using Ubuntu 21.10 Impish.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try a lower resolution. Btw, an internet search gives a lot of people having the same error --> `android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Error 0xfffffff4`.

Comment: Does `scrcpy --render-driver=opengles2` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [pLumo](https://askubuntu.com/users/631600/plumo) for helping me :)

For anyone who has the same error, the problem was with the unsupported resolution. You need to change the resolution to somewhere near `1024` to get it to work. You can do it by running:

```
scrcpy -m 1024
```

You may want to increase or decrease the resolution to adjust for your device.

---

If you have installed `scrcpy` using `sudo snap install scrcpy`, then  you will also face a lot of errors!

In this case, start by removing it:

```
sudo snap remove scrcpy
```

Now you need to compile it from source or install it using `apt`.

- Compiling from source:

  As [Romain Vimont](https://github.com/rom1v) says in [Build.md](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/blob/master/BUILD.md), you need to follow the following steps to manually compile `scrcpy`:

  > First, you need to install the required packages:
  >
  > ```
  > # for Debian/Ubuntu
  > sudo apt install ffmpeg libsdl2-2.0-0 adb wget \
  >                  gcc git pkg-config meson ninja-build libsdl2-dev \
  >                  libavcodec-dev libavdevice-dev libavformat-dev libavutil-dev \
  >                  libusb-1.0-0 libusb-1.0-0-dev
  > ```
  >
  > Then clone the repo and execute the installation script ([source](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/blob/master/install_release.sh)):
  >
  > ```
  > git clone https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy
  > cd scrcpy
  > ./install_release.sh
  > ```
- Installing from `apt`:

  As [Romain Vimont](https://github.com/rom1v) says in [README.md](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/blob/master/README.md), you need to follow the following steps to install `scrcpy` using `apt`:

  > On Debian and Ubuntu:
  >
  > ```
  > apt install scrcpy
  > ```

If you still have issues, then you can start a new issue at [scrcpy's GitHub page](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/issues).